# mdDialog with templateUrl and buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, modal-dialog

Is it possible to make use of the templateUrl and also have the ok and cancel buttons?

For example, I have this function in my controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function() {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({
        title: 'Form',
        templateUrl: 'src/modalTest.html',
        ok: 'Yes',
        cancel: 'No',
    });
}
```

Because I have the templateUrl in there, it just takes the html from there. But the buttons don't appear. However, if I change templateUrl to htmlContent and place whatever I had in the .html file into a string for htmlContent, the buttons will appear.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

Sorry in advance if this is a noob question! Still learning about dialogs and modals.